# Wi-fi not showing up on Network options with High Sierra - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I just updated my macbook-pro mid 2010 to High Sierra and the Wi-fi disappeared completely.

I've tried to **run apple hardware test** and got and error -3403D.

Then I **booted into safe mode** and nothing happened.

Then I **Ran the terminal with commands** and wi-fi didn't show up in the list, only Ethernet and FireWire. It said "Wi-fi is not a recognised network service ** Error: The parameters were not valid" And then "You cannot set Wi-fi power because all AirPort network services are disabled"

I don't know what to do next!!! Please help!!!!!

I hope somebody here has a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It looks like the Wi-Fi module has failed. But all is not lost, you could use a wireless USB adapter, for example: https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/archer-t2u-nano/. Search the web for "mac usb wifi" to get other results. Important: look for support for your version of OS X.

Comment: I've been using an old cellphone for USB tethering and works fine, maybe this wireless adapter are the same, still Im gonna check it out, thanks.